# Finding the molecular formula given combustion data

Tags: stoichiometry

> $\pu{150 cm^3}$ of oxygen were added to $\pu{20 cm^3}$ of a gaseous hydrocarbon D.
> After explosion and cooling, the gaseous mixture occupied $\pu{130 cm^3}$
> and, after absorption by potassium hydroxide, $\pu{90 cm^3}$ of oxygen remained.

$$\ce{C_xH_y + (x + \frac{y}{4}) O2 -> x CO2 + y/2 H2O}$$

$\ce{C_xH_y}$: $\pu{20 cm^3}$

Why is $(x+y/4) \ce{O2} = \pu{150 cm^3} - \pu{90 cm^3}$
and $\ce{x CO2} = \pu{130 cm^3} - \pu{90 cm^3}$ ?

I genuinely don't know why.why do we subtract 90 from both sides and not just the product? Why are we subtracting 90 from the $\ce {CO2}$

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic expressions and keeping it this way until all is ready to plug in literal numbers. It helps in focusing on principles, mistakes are easier to spot, orientation is improved, Q/A is reusable and has bigger  permanent value.

Comment: Its not that hard to read off.

Answer (score 1):

- $\pu{20 cm^3}$ is the volume of the hydrocarbon.
- $\pu{130 cm^3} - \pu{90 cm^3} = \pu{40  cm^3}$
  is the volume of  $\ce{CO2}$ absorbed in the hydroxide, therefore $x=\frac{\pu{40 cm^3}}{\pu{20 cm^3}} = 2$.
- $\pu{150 cm^3} - \pu{90 cm^3} = \pu{60  cm^3}$ is volume of spent $\ce{O2}$.
- Therefore $x + \frac{y}{4} = \frac{\pu{60 cm^3}}{\pu{20 cm^3}} = 3 \implies y = 4 \implies \ce{C_xH_y} = \ce{C2H4}$.

Comment: I still don't understand why we are taking 90cm^3 from the co2

Comment: 130 cm3 of final gas = 40 cm3 of CO2 + 90 cm3 of O2.

Answer (score 1):

If starting from $\pu{150 mL}$ $\ce{O2}$, only a part of it is used to finally obtain a residue of $\pu{90 mL}$ $\ce{O2}$, it means that $150 - 90 = \pu{60 mL}$ $\ce{O2}$ has been consumed. Now added $\ce{KOH}$ after the combustion reacts with $\ce{CO2}$ and reduces the final gas volume from $\pu{130 mL}$ to $\pu{90 mL}$. This indicates that $130 - 90 = \pu{40 mL}$ is the volume of $\ce{CO2}$ produced. Let's rewrite these results:

$\ce{
  \pu{20 mL} C_xH_y + \pu{60 mL} O2 -> \pu{40 mL} CO2 + $a$ H2O
}$

The number of moles is proportional to the volumes. So that this equation can be also rewritten so, after division by $10$:

$\ce{2 C_xH_y + 6 O2 -> 4 CO2 + $a'$ H2O}$

To get $\ce{4 C}$ atoms at right, we need: $x = 2$ in the initial hydrocarbon. The equation can be rewritten:

$\ce{2 C2H_y + 6 O2 -> 4 CO2 + $a'$  H2O}$.

And now $4$ of the $\ce{6 O2}$ are required to make $\ce{4 CO2}$. The remaining $\ce{2 O2}$ (or $\ce{4 O}$) are required to burn the $2y$ $\ce{}$ atoms and form $\ce{4 H2O}$. So $a' = 4$ and $y = 4$. And the equation becomes:

$\ce{2 C2H4 + 6 O2 -> 4 CO2 + 4 H2O}$.

This can even be more simplified :

$\ce{C2H4 + 3 O2 -> 2 CO2 + 2 H2O}$.

Comment: `@Maurice`: *I speculate*, so far, the possibility to engage the `\pu{}` command (as in *physical units*) by `mhchem` ([synopsis](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/)) escaped your eye.  Compared to your earlier approach, e.g. `$60$ mL`, the use of `$\pu{60 mL}$` has the advantage that the space will not break if the construct approaches the end of the line. If you inspect the edit, you will see that it equally may be used within the `$\ce{}$` of an *chemical equation* and can equally simplify the input / ease reading the post in case of a web browser with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Why are we taking away 90 from the co2

Comment: Why does it mean that 90cm^3 co2 has been used?